# Setting up MVC3 as an application under classic asp virtual folder - IIS7

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-authentication, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have a classic asp application that uses windows authentication.

We are now migrating this classic asp to MVC3. This will also be utilizing windows autnetication also.

When i access the mvc3 app (windows authentication) via direct link (http://mvcsite.domain.com), i am asked for windows authentication and then i can navigate the site without any problem.

When i create an application (NetSite) under classic asp virtual dir and try to get to it, i get 403 forbidden error. I have double checked authentication on NetSite application and windows authentication is enabled. So my link then becomes like http://classicasp.domain.com/NetSite. "NetSite" and mvc3 virtual dir both use the same app pool and working dir.

On 403 error i am getting following:
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous

I have set another mvc2 speciality application just like this some time back and that worked just fine. Why i am having aceess problems now, am i missing some thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Under the authentication for the NetSite, is the option for Anonymous turned off?

Sometimes if anon isn't turned off on the subsite, the client will try with anonymous first, leading to a 403 error, and it will stop there.

However, if anonymous is turned off, usually the client will still try with anon first, get a 401 error (which is expected), and then re-send with windows credentials.